# Is there a VB.NET version of this code?

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have found this amazing control that does exactly what I need, only problem, its in C#.
Does anyone know of a VB version of this code? I've tried using converters, but all of them have failed in successfully converting the project. Maybe one of you guys knows how to convert it?

Anyway, here is the control:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/FastColoredTextBox_.aspx

Apreciate any help!

Comment: Build the assembly and reference it from your vb project.

Comment: You can access any methods from C# in VB.NET, just make a DLL first and add it to your project

Comment: yeah but then I would need to ship the dll along with the project, right? And I need to add some custom features to the textbox as well, as I already have a custom text box and I need to merge them into 1.

Comment: In that case, try using this C# to vb.net converter: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: What classes cannot be converted by your converter? I would use this: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
If you would mention a class we could convert it, but not without any informations because this project consists of many classes.

Comment: yeah I've tried using that but the entire project becomes one big error, and some errors appear that I can't solve as clicking them won't bring up any text

Comment: Ok, ive converted the project and now I have been left with 2097 errors... Please help!

Comment: Really, please just add it to a separate class library project. Windows setup can bundle the dll in with your installer, and then you can inherit from the control to add your own customizations.

Comment: Why don't you just convert it yourself? If you know VB.Net, you're half the way there to knowing C# - you're just using the .Net Framework. I programmed in VB.Net for 5+ years and had no problem catching on to C#. Give it a shot - you may find it easier than you think.

Comment: Ah, thanks everyone I think inheriting the control will do just fine. And yes, I can also program in C# (maybe even better then in VB.NET) but this project is enormous. But thanks, I'm inheriting the file now and its working great =D. Thanks!

Comment: @Qub1 You should accept Corey's answer (click on the hollow tick next to the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you compile this into its own assembly and then reference it as a control? That way, you wouldn't have to port it to VB.net.

Comment: Yeah but I've already made a custom control which inherits the richtextbox control and its written in VB.NET, thus I need to merge the 2 controls into 1.

Comment: Qub - Inherit this instead of richtextbox. You can bundle the assembly together with your program in your setup project.

Answer (score -1):

We have used [Instant VB](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html) to convert tens of thousands of lines of code from C# to VB and they are pretty helpful if you run into conversion issues.